# Ant-TestNG classpath issue: getResource can't find the file

Tags: java, ant, classpath, testng

I got a TestNG test, that works perfectly fine on it's own. Somewhere in it I got:

```
URL fileName = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("config.properties");
```

I'm trying to run the same test using Ant:

```
<testng outputDir="${resultsFolder}" haltOnFailure="false">
  <classpath>
      <fileset dir="./src/">
        <include name="**/*.properties"/>
      </fileset>
            -----------------------------...--------------------
 </classpath>
 <classfileset dir="correct path here" includes="**/*.class" />
</testng>
```

I can see in debug mode that the config.properties is in the classpath. But the line at the top can not find it, it is null.

EDIT: I solved it.The critical line actually does not search for the file in the classpath directly, it searches IN the files/folders. So, this solved my problem:

```
<pathelement location="src/"/>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: is config.properties in a sub-folder under src?

Comment: No, it's not. It was in the src folder, but at this point I'm trying different things with it. When I
    System.out.println(System.getProperties().getProperty("java.class.path"));

config.properties is actually there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace your `<classpath>...</classpath>` with this:

```
<classpath>
     <pathelement path="./src"/>
</classpath>
```

In order for JVM to find the `config.properties` the parent directory of `config.properties` should be in classpath.

Comment: Maybe you can close the tag. My XML got invalidated after copying this :)